# Distribution and probabilities for basketball game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, game-theory

Shortly the task says, that we have two basketball teams. Predictably first team will win by $3.5$ points. Also, with probability $p_1=0.5$, first team will win by $4,5,6,7,\ldots$ points (mark $-4,-5,-6,\ldots$) or with probability $p_2=1-p_1=0.5$ first will win by $3,2,1$ points OR lose with any result ($-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$).

1. With which distribution can we calculate the probabilities that first team will win by any number of points ($\ldots,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,\dots$)?
2. Calculate probability that the difference of points between two teams will be in interval  $[6,10]$.

I'm new in MSE and in this field/ Really need help with this task or some hints. Is it enough data to calculate these things?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @dantopa ok, I read it. But maybe have you some advices how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify your question a bit more? What do you mean by *"...predictably first team will win by 3.5.."* and is your $p_1$ the probability that the first team will win by $4$ or more points?

Comment: Hi @SatwikPasani . In the given for me task is written that most likely the game will end with $\sim 3.5$ difference between teams. This exercise is with odds math but I'm not sure it has impact in the solution. Yes, $p_1$  says that the first team will win by 4 or more points, and $p_2$ for other results. I will be really grateful if you can help me, because I first time see this kind of problem but it's important for me.

Comment: @SatwikPasani I read few times the exercise again and understood that 3.5 we can treat like the MEAN

Answer (score 0):

This is a poorly posed question.  Certainly it is impossible that the first team will win by $3.5$ points.  It could be that the mean score difference is $3.5$.  That gives you one constraint on the distribution function of the score difference.  For point $1$ what distribution is the question referring to?  If it is the distribution of the score difference, we can use any distribution to compute the probability.  Just look at the value of the distribution at that point differential.  For point $2$ it depends on the distribution.  One distribution that satisfies the requirement is that the point differential is either $3$ or $4$ with each having probability $0.5$.  The chance the difference is in $[6,10]$ is then zero.  Another is that the differential is either $8$ or $-1$ with each having probability $0.5$.  Then the chance the difference is in $[6,10]$ is $0.5$.  There are an infinite number of other distributions with other chances that the difference is in $[6,10]$

Comment: Yes, I wrote actually in comment that 3.5 here we can understand like the mean but the task was given in the way I write it here and believe me, for me it also sounds strange.  It isn't logical I think that just 3 or 4. It's the task from real life, real game, not the textbook. The task says: p1=0.5 that first team win by 4 or more points and p2=0.5 that first team lose with any result or win by 3,2,1,0. So which distribution do you recommend for the part 2? Maybe Poisson?

Comment: There is not enough information to determine the distribution.  I gave two examples that fit the requirement and give different answers to the question.  Clearly it should be some sort of bell shaped distribution, but even if you decide it should be (a discretized version of) normal you don't have any way to assess the standard deviation.

Comment: what about Poisson with parameter $\lambda=3.5$? It will be similiar to bell shape I think.

Comment: That would have about $0.5366$ of the results below $3.5$, not $0.50$ as specified.   $\lambda \approx 3.672$ has $0.50$ of the results $3$ or below.  It still will not have any negative results because the Poisson distribution cuts off at $0$.

Comment: So is it impossible to make such a distribution to suit it?

Comment: No, it is quite possible.  I gave two in my original answer.  You could make a binomial distribution of the number of heads in an odd number of coin tosses, then shift the mean to $3.5$ by subtracting.  There are lots more.  The original spec was just one constraint on the distribution, which has an infinite number of degrees of freedom

Comment: Maybe can you show how to do it with binomial distribution? I will be really grateful. @RossMillikan

Comment: Take the binomial distribution of $13$ coin tosses, which ranges from $0$ to $13$ with mean $6.5$.  Subtract $3$ from the result and you will have a distribution that ranges from $-3$ to $+10$ with $0.5$ chance of exceeding $3.5$.  Substitute any odd number $n$ for $13$ and subtract $\frac n2-3.5$ for another version

Answer (score 0):

You should try a normal Distribution with continuity correction, and make some assumptions on the standard deviation.